# Conda resolution strategies

Tags: conda

In Maven and Gradle there are resolution strategies for handling the case when two different dependencies depend on different versions of a third dependency (for example: A->B->D@1.7 and A->C->D@2.1).

Apparently in Maven the default strategy is "choose nearest" [1] and in Gradle it's  "choose highest" [2]. Is this a thing you can configure similarly (I'd like to use "choose highest") in Conda?

[1] https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html
[2] https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/gradle-beyond-the/9781449373801/ch04.html